# App Engine Can't get appId from Remote API Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, remoteapi

I have used Remote API to have access of Remote Datastore, with authentication options: Google Account API. In my code i have done proper servlet entries in web.xml. Then too, I am getting error log as:

> Uncaught exception from servlet
>   java.io.IOException: can't get appId from remote api; status code = 404
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.getAppIdFromServer(RemoteApiInstaller.java:304)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.loginImpl(RemoteApiInstaller.java:267)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.login(RemoteApiInstaller.java:228)

I have also tried it for different SDKs (1.5.2 & 1.6.4) but I am getting the same log.

My web.xml code is:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>Remote API Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CPUstats</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.CPUstatsServlet </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CPUstats</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cpustats</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
.
.
.
```

The command-line I am running is:

```
..\bin>appcfg.cmd -e gggodhwani@gmail.com --enable_jar_splitting update C:\Gaurav\New-projects\Crawler1.4\war
```

Comment: Have you uploaded the version of the app with remote_api enabled? You're getting a 404 either because remote_api is not enabled, or because it's on a different URL to the one you are hitting.

Comment: Yes I have uploaded the version with remote api enabled, also URL is also correct.

Comment: Well, one of those things isn't the case, or you wouldn't be getting a 404. There's no way to tell without seeing - at least - your web.xml and the command line you're entering.

Comment: I have added web.xml code and command to deploy the project.

Comment: I meant the command you're using to invoke remote_api, not to upload the app.